# Comparing variables for objects in ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java

I tried searching, but to no avail, I hope you can help me out.

I have an `ArrayList` containing objects, which all have 4 integer variables. I want my program to throw an `Exception`, if some of the variables for these objects are identical.. I'll try and write in pseudocode:

```
for(Object x : ArrayList)
{
    if(x.Variable == someVariables)// all the variables for the objects in the arraylist
    {
        throw exception
    }
}
```

This is a newbie question, but I hope you can help me out, thanks.

Comment: Is this pseudocode or your actual code? Don't expect us to comment on your code, if you don't show us your code. What is it you are having trouble with?

Comment: Please add your object that contains the integer values

Answer (score 1):

Inside your for loop add them into a set if add method returns false duplicate exist

```
for(Object x : ArraList)
{
  Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<Integer>();
  for(int i:x.getAllValues()){
      boolean status=set.add(i)
      if(status==false){
        //throw exception
      }
  }
}
```

write get values method in your object class

**OR**

Simply create a set from list and check their length

```
Set<Integer> set= new HashSet<Integer>(list);
if(set.size()!=list.size()){
//contains duplicates
}
```

Comment: You can just create a set from the list and then see whether the sizes match.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: It's not about checking wether the list contains just unique vaules, it's about the checking of the individual objects of the list, if they have a valid state (all 4 member vars have to be unique)

Answer (score 1):

Id recommend to implement your value check inside of your class which is your `Object`'s type. To me it seems to be important that a "thing" like your `Object` is able to perform a validity check on it's own values. I give you an example:

```
public class Container {

    // declaration of your four variables

    // other code, maybe getters and setters

    /**
     * Checks if all variables are pairwise inequal
     * @return true if so, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isValid() {      
        // check vars
    }
}
```

This way your routine to check all objects of your list is very easy:

```
for (Container x : arrayList) {
    if (!x.isValid()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("A bad thing just happend!");
    }
}
```